Evaluation of an Integral Involving the Lower Incomplete Gamma Function Raised to a Positive Integer Power
I am trying to evaluate the following integral involving the lower incomplete Gamma function raised to the power of a positive integer $N$:
$\int_0^{\infty} x^{\mu-1} e^{-\beta x} \gamma(\nu, \alpha x)^N \, dx$
I know the following relation from the  Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's Table of integrals in (6.455)
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty} x^{\mu-1} e^{-\beta x} \gamma(\nu, \alpha x) \, dx = \frac{\alpha^\nu \Gamma(\mu + \nu)}{\nu (\alpha + \beta)^{\mu + \nu}} \, {}_2F_1\left(1, \mu + \nu; \nu + 1; \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta}\right)
\end{equation}
However, how to handle the case when the Gamma function is raised to the power of a positive integer $N$ and is there a related references for this case.

This was asked here too. Possibly expanding $\gamma(v,ax)^N$ as multiple sums or substituting $\gamma(v,ax)=u$ and using its inverse’s series could work too. There does not seem to be a simple answer.
